# Bring parent widget on top of widget that has Qt::Toolip Flag

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a widget that must cover the whole screen, including Taskbar and I don't want this widget to appear itself on the Taskbar, that's why I have set the Attribute flag to `Qt::ToolTip` and that works fine.

Now the problem that I have is that I have another widget, which functions as a parent widget (much smaller then the child) is always below the child widget. I have tried to bring the parent up with `show()`, `activateWindow()`, `rise()` and setting `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` Attribute on the parent, doesn't help.

Is there any way to bring it up or is it just impossible wit `Qt::ToolTip`? I have tried also other options like `Qt::Tool` or `Qt::Dialog` with similar behavior.

Without setting `Qt::ToolTip`, `Qt::Dialog` or `Qt::Tool` the parent comes to top when I call `parent->activateWindow()`.